# Cutting an image with c#, memorystream, graphics and image

Tags: c#, image, memory, graphics

i have a problem with cutting an image.

What i want to do is, to cut an image in some slices, mostly quadratic.
The code isn't yet refined for boundary values and shouldn't cut the whole image in an approriate size, but thats currently not the problem.

My problem is, that the first image which has been cut is really a part of the original image, but the 2nd image (or all after it) are only black. i am just at a dead end and i don't know what the problem is.

```
            var sourceImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(args[numcount]);

                int cutsizeHeight = sourceImg.Height < cutsize ? sourceImg.Height : cutsize;
                int cutsizeWidht = sourceImg.Width < cutsize ? sourceImg.Width : cutsize;

                int cutPassesHeight = (int)(sourceImg.Height / cutsize) == 0 ? 1 : (int)(sourceImg.Height / cutsize);
                int cutPassesWidth = (int)(sourceImg.Width / cutsize) == 0 ? 1 : (int)(sourceImg.Width / cutsize);

                for (int i = 0; i < cutPassesHeight; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < cutPassesWidth; j++)
                    {
                        var mem = new MemoryStream();
                        var sourcePositionX = i * cutsizeHeight;
                        var sourcePositionY = j * cutsizeWidht;
                        var cutRectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, cutsizeWidht, cutsizeHeight);

                        var newImage = new Bitmap(cutRectangle.Width, cutRectangle.Height);
                        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
                        g.DrawImage(sourceImg, cutRectangle, sourcePositionX, sourcePositionY, cutsizeWidht, cutsizeHeight, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        newImage.Save(mem, ImageFormat.Png);

                        var saveImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(mem);
                        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(args[numcount]);
                        var pureName = fileName.Split('.');
                        fileName = pureName[0] + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString() + ".png";
                        saveImage.Save(@"C:\usr\test\" + fileName);
                    }
                }
```

This is my code snippet.
Currently i am testing it with an imagesize 5906 * 1773. The slice dimensions per cutted image should be 2096 * 1773. The code above ignores therefore the rest of 1714 in the width (2096 * 2 = 4192, rest of 5906 - 4192 = 1714). But thats okay, though.

The problem is, that the second one won't be the image, but it is black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution is: Use the original code but this was wrong, so instead of using:

```
var sourcePositionX = i * cutsizeHeight;
var sourcePositionY = j * cutsizeWidht;
```

it's correct to use:

```
var sourcePositionY = i * cutsizeHeight;
var sourcePositionX = j * cutsizeWidht;
```

X at the coordinate system stands for width, i just made a small X/Y mistake here. now it works.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are moving the image that you draw to the right and down instead of to the left and up. You will be drawing the source image completely outside the new image:

```
First image:  Second image:     Third image:
+---+----+    +---+--------+    +---+    +--------+
| d |    |    | d |        |    | d |    |        |
+---+    |    +---+    s   |    +---+    |    s   |
|     s  |        |        |             |        |
+--------+        +--------+             +--------+
```

Use negative coordinates:

```
var sourcePositionX = -i * cutsizeHeight;
var sourcePositionY = -j * cutsizeWidht;
```

---

On a side note; you are saving the image to a memory stream, then you load it from the memory stream and save it to a file. Just save it to the file directly.

Comment: that didn't do the trick, the 2nd image is still black here. i suspect that something is wrong with the rectangle or withg the g.DrawImage; which i'll investigate tomorrow.
a comment on your side node: if i save i directly, c# throws an out of memory exception. this memorystream thingy pumps a performance and can handle bigger files.

Comment: @TonyB: I see, you are also using an overload of `DrawImage` that scales the image. Use this overload instead, that only takes the image and the destination coordinates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/558kfzex.aspx

Comment: Still not working. Now the image will be scaled and the 2nd image will be black again.

Comment: @TonyB: I tested the code with using negative coordinates and the overload that doesn't scale the image, and it works fine.

Comment: @TonyB: Use `int cutPassesHeight = (sourceImg.Height+cutsize) / cutsize;` to calculate a number of pieces that covers all of the image. Also, you got `i` and `j` mixed up; `i` is the vertical couinter, but it's used to calculate the horisontal coordinate.